# Excel function for ranking duplicate values

Tags: excel, duplicates, rank

I have an excel sheet containing two columns of data that I'd like to rank.

Suppose we have the following:

```
    A        B
    Franz    58
    Daniel   92
    Markus   37
    Jörg     58
```

I would like a formula to rank the above data based on column B, and where there are duplicate values (Franz and Jörg) to put the alphabetical name first. What I have at the moment is simply duplicating Franz twice:

```
     =INDEX(Name,MATCH(A2,Points,0))
```

Can someone advise me of formula / code that will rank the data and arrange duplicate values alphabetically?

Thanks

Comment: Sort by those columns in the order you need: Define your sorting order, first by column B and then by column A.

Comment: Do you need a function that returns the array of sorted (ranked) values?

Comment: I need this to be a formula or function, not something that has to be *manually* sorted. The formula that I have cannot sort by one then the other, as upon performing the first sort the duplicate names are already created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would add a helper column in next to your data to help out with ties.
so in column C use

```
=B1+1/COUNTIF($A$1:$A$4,"<="&A1)/10
```

This will add on a decimal ranking system based on the name. This assumes that your numbers in column B do not have decimal places, if they do then you will need to increase the 10 on the end of the formula to account for it ie: for 2 decimal places use 1000, 3 : 10000 etc

Use this formula to get the first name

```
=INDEX(name,MATCH(LARGE(points,1),points,0))
```

adjust the 1 to 2 for the second name etc

*EDIT* had the sign around the wrong way

Comment: Here's a new one for you. If we had the same four people, with Franz and Jörg again tied on points, but we wanted to sort not alphabetically but by the lowest value for each person in columns C to G (i.e. their best result), what formula should be used?

Comment: The deeper you go with trying to rank these users with formulas the better off you would be with putting the data into a pivot table, this will make it very easy to rank any way you like.

Answer (score 2):

This will rank your data and will not repeat duplicates too:

In C2:

```
=SUM(1*(b2>$b$2:$b$5))+1+IF(ROW(b2)-ROW($b$2)=0,0,SUM(1*(b2=OFFSET($b$2,0,0,INDEX(ROW(b2)-ROW($b$2)+1,1)-1,1))))
```

CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to turn it into an array

Drag these down to C5 and it will not duplicate rank where the name is the same, it will rank them alphabetically if they are the same.

Then if you wanted to order them automatically in order of top performer/score you then do this:

Putting this in E2:

```
=INDEX(A2:A5,MATCH(LARGE(C2:C5,ROW()-1),C2:C5,0))
```

...and drag down

Then use a vlookup on your data to return the score putting this in F2:

```
=vlookup(E2,A2:C5,2,false)
```

...and drag down

This should give you a table of highest scoring people in score order.

Comment: Using your second formula, with the ROW()-1 aspect, it completely omits the person who ranks highest. You need to use ROW()-2 to capture the highest scorer. Other than that, this is a very good example, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming A2 is the first of the ranked points scores try this version

`=INDEX(Name,SMALL(IF(A2=Points,ROW(Points)-MIN(ROW(Points))+1),COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)))`

confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER and copied down

Requires the Name list to be sorted because names with duplicate scores will be listed in the order shown